# Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. By applying Markov’s inequality show that

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am looking for confirmation that I am working in the correct direction as well as pointers for points where I have gone astray. Here is the problem.

(a) Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $0$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. By applying Markov’s inequality to the random variable $W = (X + t)^2, t > 0$, show that

$$P (X \geq a) \leq \dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2 + a^2}\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{for any $a$} > 0.$$

(b) Hence show that, for any $a > 0$,
$$P(Y \geq \mu+a)\leq\sigma^2+a2$$
 where $E(Y) = \mu, \;var(Y) = \sigma^2$.

(c) A set of $200$ people consisting of $100$ men and $100$ women is randomly divided into $100$ pairs of $2$ each. Number the men arbitrarily from $1$ to $100$, and for $i = 1,2,...,100$, let
$$z_i=\begin{cases}
1;\qquad\text{if man i is paired with a woman}\\
0;\qquad else
\end{cases}$$

Let Z be the number of these pairs that consist of a man and a woman,
$$z=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}z_i$$
(i) Find E(Z).

(ii) Find var(Z).

(iii) Using (b), give an upper bound to the probability that Z ≤ 30.

**Attempt:**

Part (a) seems fairly straight forward, thus,
\begin{align}
P(X\geq a)&=P(X+t-t\geq a)\\
&=P(X+t\geq t+ a)\\
&\leq P((X+t)^2\geq (a+t^2))\\
&\leq \dfrac{E((X+t)^2)}{E((a+t)^2)}\qquad\text{by Markov inequality }\\
&=\dfrac{var(t)}{var(a+t)}\qquad\text{by definition on expectation}\\
&=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}
\end{align}

(b)

For this one i feel as though i have made a fallacy; nonetheless, See that
\begin{align}
P(Y\leq \mu+a)&\leq P(Y^2\leq \mu^2+a^2)\\
&=\dfrac{E((Y)^2)}{E((\mu^2+a^2))}\\
&=\dfrac{var(Y)}{var(\mu)+var(a^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}
\end{align}

(c) (i)

For this one i feel it should just be as follows,
\begin{align}
E(z)&=E(\sum_{i=1}^{100}z_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{100}E(z_i)\\
&=\dfrac{(100)(101)}{2}\\
&=5050
\end{align}
However, I suspect that it cannot be that simple as when I apply the same logic to find $var(z)$ I end up with a negative number. But how can this be? I must be making a mistake somewhere.

(iii)

Amended

On further inspection I see we should use the results found in the previous parts. thus, we want to use
\begin{align}
P(z\leq\mu +a)\leq\dfrac{\sigma^2}{sigma^2+a^2}
\end{align}
where $\sigma^2$ comes from the variance found previously and $a$ is given to be 30.

Comment: $E[Z]$ cannot exceed $100$ and is likely to be about half that.  I would have thought $E[Z] = \sum E[Z_i] = 100 \Pr(Z_i=1) = \frac{10000}{199} \approx 50.25126$

Comment: For future reference, you might get a response sooner if you make your post smaller by focusing on just one part. You are free to make a new post once you've resolved a previous one.

Comment: Could you also check if you have typed out everything correct, I find there might be typos in your text.  I can't follow your solution that well!!

Comment: I have updated my (incomplete) answer. Hopefully, it should give you leads and directions to continue and finish the problem.

Comment: @ClementC.  Oh, I am sorry!!.  I did not load your answer, my comment was on the OP's answer.  My apologies!!

Comment: @satishramanathan Oh, no worries.

Answer (score 4):

You have made some mistakes for (a)-(b): (so I did not go further, haven't fully checked your (c))

- Writing $\operatorname{Var} t$, $\operatorname{Var} (a+t)$ is a good sign something went wrong: $a,t$ are constants here (the r.v. is $X$ or $Y$), so both variances are... $0$.
- Another one is that $(\mu+a)^2 \neq \mu^2+a^2$ in general:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}\{Y \geq \mu+a\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{Y^2 \geq (\mu+a)^2\}\neq \mathbb{P}\{Y^2 \geq \mu^2+a^2\}
  $$
- Another one is that $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \operatorname{Var} Y + \mathbb{E}[Y]^2$, *not* $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \operatorname{Var} Y$.

What you *can* do is to apply (for any parameter $t\geq 0$) Markov's inequality to the (non-negative) random variable $X_t\stackrel{\rm def}{=}(Y-\mu +t)^2$ (here, I am dealing directly with the case (b) of general mean $\mu$, for (a) you can basically take $\mu=0$), so that
$$
\mathbb{P}\{Y \geq \mu+a\}
= \mathbb{P}\{Y - \mu + t \geq a + t\}
\leq \mathbb{P}\{X_t \geq (a+t)^2\}
\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_t]}{(a+t)^2}
= \frac{\operatorname{Var} Y + t^2}{(a+t)^2}
$$
(the last equality requires expanding the square to verify that $\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \operatorname{Var} Y + t^2$.) Now, this holds for *any* $t\geq 0$, so you can differentiate and maximize the RHS for the "best possible $t$, which will give you what you want.

*Remark:* this is actually called "one-sided Chebyshev," or more accurately [Cantelli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantelli%27s_inequality).

---

Followup on (c):

By linearity of expectation (why do you have an $\infty$ bound on your sum, by the way?),
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{E}[Z_i]
= \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{P}\{ Z_i =1 \}
$$
Now, fix any $i$. The probability that man $i$ is paired with a woman is exactly $\frac{100}{200-1}=\frac{100}{199}$ (there are 199 other people, 100 of which being women). Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = 100\cdot \frac{100}{199} = \frac{10000}{199}.
$$

How did you get $\frac{100\cdot 101}{2}$?

- For the variance:
  We do not have linearity anymore, but we can use the fact that 
  $$
  \operatorname{Var} Z = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] - \mathbb{E}[Z]^2.
  $$
  The second term, we have it, so let us compute the first:
  $$\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[Z^2]  &= \mathbb{E}\left[  \left(\sum_{i=1}^{100} Z_i \right)^2 \right]
  = \mathbb{E}\left[  \sum_{i=1}^{100} Z_i^2 + 2\sum_{i<j} Z_iZ_j \right]
  = \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{E}\left[  Z_i^2 \right] + 2\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq 100}\mathbb{E}\left[  Z_iZ_j \right] \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^{100} \mathbb{E}\left[  Z_i \right] + 2\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq 100}\mathbb{E}\left[  Z_iZ_j \right]
  = \mathbb{E}\left[ Z \right] + 2\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq 100}\mathbb{E}\left[  Z_iZ_j \right]
  \end{align}$$
  where in the end we used the fact that $Z_i^2=Z_i$ as $Z_i\in\{0,1\}$. Furthermore, for $i\neq j$
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left[  Z_iZ_j \right]
  = \mathbb{P}\{ Z_i=Z_j=1 \}
  = \mathbb{P}\{ Z_i=1 \mid Z_j=1 \}\mathbb{P}\{ Z_j=1 \}
  = \mathbb{P}\{ Z_i=1 \mid Z_j=1 \}\frac{100}{199}
  = \frac{99}{197}\cdot\frac{100}{199}
  $$
  since if $j$ is paired with a women, there remain $99$ women among the $197$ people that are neither $i,j$ or the women paired with $j$.
  Therefore,
  $$\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[Z^2]  &= 100\cdot \frac{100}{199} + \binom{100}{2}\frac{99}{197}\cdot\frac{100}{199}
  \end{align}$$
  and along with $\mathbb{E}[Z]^2$ this will give you the variance.

Comment: Incidentally: numbers are complicated, so there may be typos or mistake due tothe use of $100$. I'd suggest doing everything in (c) with $100$ replaced by $n$ ($n$ men and $n$ women), and only plugging $n=100$ at the very end.

Comment: For part (b) I follow right up to the end. We get the expression $$\dfrac{var(Y)+t^2}{(a+t)^2}$$ which we want to optimize for the smallest value of $t$, as you pointed out. However, can we assume that $var(y)=0$ so we are just meant to optimize $$\dfrac{t^2}{(a+t)^2}$$ in which case we find this occurs when $t=\sigma.$ Then substituting $t=\sigma$ and $var(y)=0$ into $$\dfrac{var(Y)+t^2}{(a+t)^2}$$ gives the desired result of $$\dfrac{\sigma^2}{(a+\sigma^2)}.$$

Comment: No, we cannot assume the variance of Y is zero. If it were the case, then Y would be a constant almost surely...

Comment: (To get the right result, you have to carry the variance, i.e. sigma^2, in the numerator when optimizing. It is not a big deal, as it is just a constant when optimizing wrt t)

Comment: I think I am with you now. $var(y)=\sigma^2$, which is just a constant. After differentiating and setting equal to zero we get the optimal value of t is given by $$t=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{a}.$$ We then substitute this back into our function and it all collapses down to the desired result.

Comment: @Jeremy yes, exactly.

Comment: I am also still having trouble with the variance. You stated the relation $var(Z)=E(Z^2)-E(Z)$, but for some reason I seem to recall it is given as $var(Z)=E(Z^2)-(E(Z))^2$. However, this second way leeds me to a negative number. Clearly, if i get a negative number it cannot be correct. However, when I follow the method you set out I get that $var(Z)=1250$. This also does not seem correct to me.

Comment: This is a typo, i forgot a square. Will edit. (Edited.)